# How to set an icon to a class?

Tags: html, css

I want a div class in my code to have an icon in the beginning (or after) the content in the div. Basically what I did was to copy and paste the glyphicon CSS into the desired class CSS (And use `:before` and `:after` to specify the position)

So basically the div is as follows:

```
<div class="leaf in-leaf">in-elem1</div>
```

And CSS:

```
/*set leaf node css*/

.leaf {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
}


/*set arrow head at the right of leaf*/

.in-leaf:after {
    content: "\e072";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

For the result:
[image]

Is there a better way to do this than using the same glyphicon CSS? Maybe a way to simply bind glyphicon to the class?

Comment: You can use it the way you are using. Default glyp comes out without positions. So you need it customize as your requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override styles for class `.glyphicon` and `.glyphicon:before` whenever it used with some other class like `.leaf` and then you can use any `.glyphicon` that you need as shown in below snippet:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.leaf-holder {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
}

.leaf.glyphicon {
  display: block;
  line-height: 20px;
  top: auto;
}

.leaf.glyphicon:before {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="leaf-holder">
<div class="leaf glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right">in-elem1</div>
</div>
<div class="leaf-holder">
<div class="leaf glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger">in-elem1</div>
</div>
<div class="leaf-holder">
<div class="leaf glyphicon glyphicon-apple">in-elem1</div>
</div>
<div class="leaf-holder">
<div class="leaf glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right">in-elem1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Basically what I was looking for was a way to reduce repetition of code. By assigning a class to a div(probably 1 class) and it will hold an icon.

Comment: @SachDan Any icon service whether it is Glyph icons, Font Awesome or some other, I think we need minimum 2 classes 2 show any icon. And if you wants to use that icon on a `<div>` then one class for that div will also be needed. Any shorter way than this looks not possible in my opinion.

Comment: Your solution is more elegant than mine - have to agree.

Comment: But can I know why you suggest yours is better?

Comment: @SachDan In your varient, if you wants to use 15 or 20 different icons on divs then you need to write some styles for each `div` like `content: "\e072";` as each icon will have its own unique code. While in that variant which i posted above you will define generic styles once and then you can use it anywhere you wants without any further overriding.